# FloatingActionButton OnClickListener not working

Tags: android, floating-action-button

There are no Errors what so ever. However, you can see that it's being clicked on the animation. The Java code is being called from a child activity where its parent activity is MyMainActivity.

I will also include the github for the project just incase someone wanted to try it.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fav_button);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.v("CLICKED","");
        }
    });
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.lopic.movies.DetailActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/activity_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/original_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Title"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/poster"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/vote_avg"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/vote_avg"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/release_date"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/release_date"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/trailer_button"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:paddingRight="5dp"
                            android:text="Watch Trailer" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Overview"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/overview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fav_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_white_24px"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting no errors and animation is working then everything seems to be fine.

But, I guess you are using `Log` in wrong way. Right now, you have made:

```
Log.v("CLICKED","");
```

which means that print `message = ""` with `TAG = CLICKED`. If you want to see something meaningful in the LogCat use something like this:

```
Log.v("myTag","FAB Clicked");
```

Comment: My laziness. Thank you

Comment: @Lopic Glad it helped you! Happy coding)

Answer (score 5):

Programmatically bringing the FAB to front should also work:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) 
findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.bringToFront();
fab.setOnClickListener... //etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the onClick event within the xml. `android:onClick="yourMethod"`

Answer (score 0):

onClickListener is actually working fine. When you click on the fab button its going inside the method.

The below line is getting executed. Try putting-

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.v("CLICKED","");

        }
    });
```

Instead of

`Log.v("CLICKED","");`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputations for commenting.

I've put this in my onCreate()

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FloatingActionButton floatingactionbutton = findViewById(R.id.main_FloatingActionButton_addDate);
    floatingactionbutton.bringToFront();
    floatingactionbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

and it doesn't work, when I said AndroidStudio "run". So I did the same with onResume() and everything is working fine. Thanks to Amit

Answer (score 0):

I had my fab button inside a coordinatorLayout which was inside my main constraint layout.

I solved the issue by removing the coordinatorLayout and making the fab a child of the my main constraint layout.

from :

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rvThreads"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

   
   
  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:textFontWeight="400"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="New"
            app:iconSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:iconTint="@color/white"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/green"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

To:

```
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/green"
    android:text="New"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textFontWeight="400"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
    app:iconSize="20dp"
    app:iconTint="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

I believe also making the cordinatorLayout the main Layout should also work.